# Algorithm for selecting random times within a window per user

Tags: c#, algorithm, random

I need to select N amount of events a day randomly, but they can't be too close to each other (M). So the N events have to be a at least M apart within a particular window (W). In this case the window I am thinking of is 12 hours.

- N = the number of events
- T = the time at which the event should occur (UTC)
- M = the minimum factor they should be apart (Hours).
- W = the window of the events (Now to Now + 12 hours).
- U = the user (probably not important to this problem)

I could probably figure this out, but I thought it would be a fun StackOverflow question and interested how people would solve it.

Thanks in advance :)

**Update: Moved answer to an answer**

Comment: You should show your effort.

Comment: Yes I will post my anser in C# code, I'd like to see code samples.

Comment: What if there are less than N events that are all M apart within W?  Should the M constraint be removed to allow N events to be selected?

Comment: When you are selecting, do you have all the events in your window or are you picking one and then querying for the next?

Comment: Also what can you say about the duration of your events? is it fixed, or not an issue?

Comment: The events can be assumed to run instantly, All events must occur within this window and must have a meet the buffer between them.

Comment: Interesting question. I recently had a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421886/generating-non-consecutive-combinations, whose ideas apply here. (See my answer).

Comment: Please remove the answer from your question and post it as an answer.

Comment: @ThiefMaster if I post it as an answer, does that automatically check my answer? If that is the case, I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

It splits the available time (window - count * minimum) randomly, then sorts the times and adds the minimum amount to produce the final event array `T[]`.

```
    static Random rnd=new Random();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double W=12;
        double M=1.0;

        int N=7;

        double S=W-(N-1)*M;
        double[] T=new double[N];

        for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
            T[i]=rnd.NextDouble()*S;
        }
        Array.Sort(T);
        for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
            T[i]+=M*i;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("{0,8} {1,8}", "#", "Time");
        for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0,8} {1,8:F3}", i+1, T[i]);    
        }

        // With N=3, Window 12h, Min. Span = 5h
        //      #     Time
        //      1    0.468
        //      2    5.496
        //      3   10.529

        // With N=7, Window 12h, Min. Span = 1h
        //      #     Time
        //      1    0.724
        //      2    2.771
        //      3    4.020
        //      4    5.790
        //      5    7.331
        //      6    9.214
        //      7   10.673
    }
```

As a check also, when minimum times completely covers the time window then the events are equally spaced. So for 3 events on a 12hr window with minimum time 6hrs this algorithm produces events at 0.0 ,6.0 and 12.0 as expected.

Comment: This is really smart, but very predictable. You can assume you will get something ever 5 hours and X minutes. Still, very smart.

Comment: I see the criticism that @KhalidAbuhakmeh said about the next event being within a predictable range and I agree.

Comment: About the predictability, I don't think it is a valid criticism. If you want N events, at least M apart, you can always predict that if event1 occurs at T, then event2 will be at least T+M. The constraints of the problem make it so. There is nothing we can do about it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the idea I had for my question here: [Generating non-consecutive combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421886/generating-non-consecutive-combinations), essentially requiring that you only solve the M=0 case.

If you want to skip the description, the algorithm is given at the end of the post, which has no unpredictable while loops etc, and is guaranteed to be O(N log N) time (would have been O(N), if not for a sorting step).

---

**Long Description**

To reduce the general M case to the M=0 case, we map each possible combination (with the "aleast M constraint") to a combination without the "at least M" apart constraint.

If your events were at `T1, T2, .., TN` such that `T1 <= T2 -M, T2 <= T3 - M ...` you map them to the events `Q1, Q2, .. QN` such that

```
Q1 = T1
Q2 = T2 - M
Q3 = T3 - 2M
...
QN = TN - (N-1)M.
```

These Q satisfy the property that `Q1 <= Q2 <= ... <= QN`, and the mapping is 1 to 1. (From `T` you can construct the `Q`, and from `Q` you can construct the `T`).

So all you need to do is generate the `Q` (which is essentially the `M=0` case), and map them back to the `T`.

Note that the window for generating `Q` becomes `[Now, Now+12 - (N-1)M]`

To solve the `M=0` problem, just generate `N` random numbers in your window and sort them.

---

**Final Algorithm**

Thus your whole algorithm will be

```
Step 1) Set Window = [Start, End - (N-1)M]
Step 2) Generate N random numbers in the Window.
Step 3) Sort the numbers generated in Step 2. Call them Q1, Q2, .. , QN
Step 4) Create Ti with the formula Ti = Qi + (i-1)M, for i = 1 to N.
Step 5) Output T1,T2,..,TN
```

Answer (score 1):

```
timeItems = new List();
int range;
double randomDouble;

for i = 1 to N
{   
   range = W/M;

   //assumes generate produces a random number between 0 and 1 (exclusive)
   randomDouble = RandomGenerator.generate() * (range); 
   T =  Math.floor(randomDouble)*M;
   timeItems.add(T);
}

return timeItems
```

Comment: This doesn't guarantee that the events will be separated by at least M hour(s).

Comment: you're right, updated the "T =  Math.floor(randomDouble)" line to incorporate M

Comment: If your random function returns two results that are close enough, they will have the same randomDouble value, resulting in two identical T values, meaning two identical values.

Comment: I don't see a problem with that. For instance if range=10, then 0.5343552324 and 0.5334645 will in effect give you a randomDouble of 5. What's wrong with that? The only part of the number you care about is the digit after the decimal

Comment: If two T values are the same, two events will occur at the same time, not separated by at least M time.

Comment: I see what you mean now. I re-read the problem, and he does imply there should be discrete events

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that events occur instantaneously (and, as such, can occur at time = end of window, you could do something like this:

```
//Using these, as defined in the question
double M;
int N;
DateTime start; //Taken from W
DateTime end; //Taken from W

//Set these up.
Random rand = new Random();
List<DateTime> times;
//This assumes that M is 
TimeSpan waitTime = new TimeSpan.FromHours(M);
int totalSeconds = ((TimeSpan)end-start).TotalSeconds;

while( times.Count < N )
{
    int seconds = rand.Next(totalSeconds);
    DateTime next = start.AddSeconds(seconds);
    bool valid = true;
    if( times.Count > 0 )
    {
        foreach( DateTime dt in times )
        {
            valid = (dt > next && ((TimeSpan)dt - next) > waitTime) ? true : false;
            if( !valid )
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if( valid )
    {
        times.Add(next);
    }
}
```

Now, in a 12 hour window with at least an hour after each event before the next, you'd best have a small N - my psuedocode above does not check to see if it's possible to fit N events into X time with M hours between each event.

Answer (score 1):

First consider the job of generating *one* event such that there are (n-1) more events to generate (need to be separated by at least M each) and total of w time left.

Time t can be in between 0 to w-(n-1)m. The average value of t should be w/(n-1). Now, use any of your favorite distribution (I recommend poisson) to generate a random number with mean w/(n-1). If the number is higher than w-n-1)m, then generate again. That will give your t.

Recursively call (offset=offset+t, w=w-t, n=n-1, m=m) to generate more numbers.

```
def generate(offset, w, n, m):
    mean = w/(n-1);
    t=ininity;
    while (t> (w-(n-1)m)):
         t= poisson( w/(n-1) )
    return [t+offset] + generate(offset+t, w-t, n-1, m)
```

I have not coded for corner conditions and other cases which I leave it to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. You get some weird behavior if your time apart and numOfEvents are conflicting. Play around with it and see what happens.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace RandomScheduler
{
    class Program
    {
        public static Random R = new Random();

        static void Main()
        {
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            var random = new Random((int)now.Ticks);
            const int windowOfHours = 12;
            const int minimumTimeApartInHours = 2;
            const int numOfEvents = 5;

            // let's start the window 8 AM
            var start = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, 8, 0, 0, 0);
            // let's end 12 hours later
            var end = start.AddHours(windowOfHours);

            var prev = null as DateTime?;
            const int hoursInEachSection = windowOfHours / numOfEvents;

            var events = new List<DateTime>();

            for (var i = 0; i < numOfEvents; i++)
            {
                // if there is a previous value
                // let's at least start 2 hours later
                if (prev.HasValue)
                    start = prev.Value.AddHours(minimumTimeApartInHours);

                DateTime? @event;
                do
                {
                    // pick a random double, so we get minutes involved
                    var hoursToAdd = random.NextDouble()*hoursInEachSection;
                    // let's add the random hours to the start
                    // and we get our next event
                    @event = start.AddHours(hoursToAdd);

                // let's make sure we don't go past the window
                } while (@event > end); 

                prev = @event;
                events.Add(@event.Value);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", events));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```